# Rails has_one forms

Tags: ruby-on-rails

i have two models:

- student - has_one locker
- locker - belongs_to student

I have a student_id in lockers table.

It is pretty simple to create a form to assign a student to locker, specially with simple_form. It is also pretty straightforward to find a locker that student has.

But how do I assign a locker to student?
Meaning, not going to locker form and select student, but rather go to student and assign a locker - which is more intuitive.

I have tried to reverse things, but it just doesn't read well: 
student belongs_to locker - this is somehow not OK to me.

My question is how do I approach this?

Thx!

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
class Student < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :locker

  def locker_id=(value)
    self.locker = Locker.find(value)
  end

  def locker_id
    locker ? locker.id : nil
  end

end
```

Then you can use `locker_id` as Student have a foreign key field.

Answer (score 0):

When you create a new locker it will automatically be assigned to a student.

for example in `Lockers_controller`

```
def new
  @student = Student.find(params[:id])
  @locker = @student.build_locker
end
```

so the `locker` is tied to the `student` already - meaning you can find a student's locker by calling `@student.locker`

Comment: Don't you mean `@student.build_locker`?